# What are final inner classes?

Tags: java, inner-classes

What does it means to declare a non-static inner class as `final`?

I have tried many links on google and [stackoverflow.com](http://www.stackoverflow.com) as well but all of them seem to be dealing about inner classes accessing final members not final inner classes itself.
I found [this](http://www.janeg.ca/scjp/overload/inner.html) link on google but even it doesn't explains it.

Thanx in advance!

Comment: Why would you expect it to mean anything different from making a top-level class final?

Comment: well because the inner-class is a class but it is also a member of the outer class. so would it be non-inheritable or there will be some other behaviour because of final?

Comment: Final is final. It means one thing only: the class cannot be extended.

Comment: Non-technical note: you should use @whoever in replying to comments, otherwise the recipient won't get notified of your comment.

Answer (score 10):

There is no semantic difference between making a top-level class `final` and making an inner class `final`: it tells the compiler that you cannot inherit from the class. Marking classes `final` is sometimes done to let the compiler skip a virtual table lookup, but this is often regarded as premature micro-optimization.

Answer (score 0):

It has the same semantics as an outer class being declared final: the class cannot be extended.

Consider this example:

```
public class MyClass {
  public class A {
  }
  public class B extends A {
  }
}
```

If you add the final modifier to A it will generate a compilation error.

Comment: thnx! also how would i extend a non-final inner class from outside the outer class? `TestClass extends MyOuter.MyInner`??

Comment: TestClass would need a constructor that takes a MyOuter. Then you call MyOuter's super method.

Comment: @SurenderThakran I think that's only possible if the inner class you're trying to extend is static. See this [inheritance matrix](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/nestedclasses.html#INHERITANCE)

Answer (score 0):

Well, inner classes are not any way different from outer classes in that context. So the following code is perfectly valid.

```
class Outer {
 int some_member;

 class Inner {
 void method();
 }
}

class OuterExtendsInner extends Outer.Inner{

}
```

As we all know, the purpose of declaring a class final is that we prevent any outside intruder from subclassing the class and exploit its facilities, the same way we can do in case of inner classes.

Comment: This gives a compilation error "No enclosing instance of type 'Outer' is in scope"